# NGXS - Can some kind soul explain this alien syntax to me

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm new to the concept of state management and of course, ngxs. I'm also not that confident with my TypeScript/JavaScript. Currently, I'm building Authentication. Good thing the official documentation have an example for some Authentication action, but I can't understand some stuff.
https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/recipes/authentication

1) 
What's this?

`const { token } = getState();`

Is it a shortcut for

```
state = getState();
const token = state.token;
```

Answer (score 1):

Its called destructuring:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

If you have an object, lets say:

```
const something = {
   prop1:1,
   prop2:2,
   prop3:3
}
```

then you can write:

```
const {prop1} = something
```

and you will get local constant named `prop1` filled with value coming from `something.prop1`.

Now, in your example, just switch object literal (`something`) for a function (`getState()`) that returns same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It is called "destructing assignment", from ES6 spec

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that
>   makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from
>   objects, into distinct variables.

Example:

```
var a, b, rest;
[a, b] = [10, 20];

console.log(a);
// expected output: 10

[a, b, ...rest] = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];

console.log(b);
// expected output: [20]
console.log(rest);
// expected output: [30,40,50]
```

Full explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment